# Cordova inAppBrowse - instantly login user

Tags: cordova, google-api, inappbrowser

Im using inappbrowser to authorize users to Google API (retrieve a token).

When I open inappbrowser with oauth url there is login to Google account form.

In default Android browser user is already signed in, 
 and what i'm trying to do is to load user session into inappbrowser to not force him to type his credentials again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just authentic directly through the mobile with [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) plugin ? It would work more intuitively and more easily with Android phones especially. (Plugin works for iOS as well). Using InAppBrowser for authentications seems strange and maybe risky.

The plugin would also allow you to perform OAuth.

Comment: i will check it out and give a feedback, thanks for now!

Comment: As is see this plugin gives possibility to user Google+ API. That's not exacly the same as Google API (Fitness API in my case). I've obtained access_token for some scopes, but wasn't able to obtain token for any of Fitness scopes.

Comment: Well, i made some misconfiguration. This plugin works also for Google Fitness API. I have some problems with getting refresh token also, but that's side problem. Thanks for help Fido, your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @dahel Glad to help.